# Kubernetes, how to mount any one of several available persistent local volumes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, azure-aks

My scenario is doing incremental builds of a huge C++ project inside a kubernetes pod. The pod runs a build upon launch and then shuts down after the build is done.

The build source code and output need to be mounted on a local nvme volume for performance reasons. Which should remain until the next build starts, which will be a new pod, but reusing the old data on disk.

The node running the build is powerful enough to run 2 such build-jobs at the same time. From the host node perspective I want to have two workspaces, `/vol/workspace1` and `/vol/workspace2`. (Actually i don't care what they are called, as long as there are 2 of them)

I want to mount **either** of these workspaces into the builder pod (as `/workspace`) upon launching the pod, **i don't want to specify explicitly which one**. If one workspace is already used it should obviously pick the second one instead, etc.

---

I'm using Azure AKS with the https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-volume-drivers/tree/master/local StorageClass if that makes any difference.

What I've tried so far is creating the StorageClass and Provisioner, but when it comes to the claim i'm only able to create static claims, such as

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-localdisk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: fast-disks
```

Which are later used in Pod spec as

```
  volumes:
    - name: localdisk
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-localdisk
```

The problem with this is that if i use `claimName: pvc-localdisk` several times they all point to the same host-directoy. If i create two distinct PersistentVolumeClaim (`pvc-localdisk1`, `pvc-localdisk2`) i don't know how to randomly select when starting pod, as `claimName` is static.

---

Edit: After more research i also found **Generic Ephemeral Volumes** https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/09/01/ephemeral-volumes-with-storage-capacity-tracking/#generic-ephemeral-volumes which sounds fairly similar except it creates a *new* local workspace every time. It looks like it should be possible to abuse this in a way that it reuses what is on disk since the storage is on the host node anyway.

Comment: Cant this be two subfolders and do your selection logic inside your code and let kubernetes always mount same volume?

Comment: That's my current fallback solution. Would preferably like to isolate the containers completely, as this is being run as a CI pre commit, to prevent any kind of accidental workspace collisions by someone putting in a ../ too many in their makefiles. Writing selection logic also means writing selection logic :) Which i was hoping K8 had built in, keeping it in K8 also means we can easily toggle between network and local disks during peak loads.

Comment: Hi HTE, I somehow feel, your intermediate build should go to some artifact storage (eg, artifactory) to exchange with other CI/CD steps. This way you remove the dependency or possible data loss. This is mostly how `build artifacts` are exchanged, Have you checked in those direction? I guess this is going very custom way and will be difficult for your team to manage/debug later.